# store git bare repository as archive

Tags: git

Is it possible to store git bare repositories in a compressed files instead of a folder structure? (And still be able to push to and pull from them.)

Background is that I need to sync a repository over a folder sync System similar to dropbox. Syncing of many small files is way slower than syncing of one moderately large file, also changes in the bare repository lead to sync conflicts in the synchronised folder.

Comment: Git already compressed the objects quite well. It could be that compressing the repo further isn’t a good idea

Comment: Get a better sync system.

Comment: Not my decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store git bare repositories in a compressed files instead of a folder structure? (And still be able to push to and pull from them.)

No.

> I need to sync a repository over a folder sync System similar to dropbox.

Wrong approach. Git is a **distributed** VCS and has quite optimized builtin mechanisms for synchronizing many remote repositories.

Comment: If it was my decision I would have installed gitlab years ago. Thanks anyways.